# wxPython Set Style text control method returns false

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to change either the background or foreground/text colour of the mouse selected line of my multiline text control widget using the `SetStyle` method, but for some reason it exits and returns false upon running the `LEFT_DCLICK` event.

I've tried to change manually its style properties without that method and it works perfectly so I suspect it isn't due to the widget not being editable. I've also checked if the properties I am setting are passed onto the style and I can confirm that they did. I suspect (based also on the method's definition) that there is some sort of mismatch between the style's declaration and the expected style parsed to the widget, but I haven't been able to identify the error yet.

```
def OnHexMouse(self, event):
    curspos = self.Hex_text.GetInsertionPoint()
    charnum, linenum = self.Hex_text.PositionToXY(curspos)
    oldstyle = self.Hex_text.GetDefaultStyle()
    newcolor = wx.Colour(255, 0, 0, 255)
    newstyle = wx.TextAttr(colText=newcolor)
    self.Hex_text.SetStyle(100, 500, newstyle)
```

Based on the values displayed on the code I am expecting red text output for the specified text range.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your issue may lie with `PositionToXY(curspos)` which in fact returns (Boolean, char, line). Also `SetStyle` expects (Start_pos, End_pos, style) which would be the cursor position plus a calculated end position. Or, for the entire line, the start would be the cursor position minus `char` and the end would be the start position plus the line length.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import wx

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Text1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "",size=(550, 200), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_RICH)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.Text1)

        self.Text1.write("0123456789012345\n")
        self.Text1.write("012345678901234567890\n")
        self.Text1.write("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n")
        self.Text1.write("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU")
        self.Text1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnHexMouse)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnHexMouse(self, event):
        curspos = self.Text1.GetInsertionPoint()
        boo, char, line = self.Text1.PositionToXY(curspos)
        line_length = self.Text1.GetLineLength(line)

        oldstyle = self.Text1.GetDefaultStyle()
        newcolor = wx.Colour(255, 0, 0, 255)
        newstyle = wx.TextAttr(colText=newcolor)

        curepos = curspos+(line_length-char)
        self.Text1.SetStyle(curspos, curepos, newstyle)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    win = TestPanel(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rolf,
so I had intentionally left all the positional variables unused because I wanted to test that the actual `SetStyle` method works in the first place. And theoretically it should have with the integer numbers I used as arguments because these are like the expected ones anyway. Anyhow, I tested it with the positional vars as well and I still got the same result. So I guess `PositiontoXY` wasn't the error's source. By the way, I don't know which version of wxPython you're using but the latter method doesn't include a boolean in the returning tuple for me.

Comment: for your interest the only difference I can detect between our codes is that my text control is declared as Read Only but not sure if that makes a difference in this case.

Comment: Based on the documentation, `SetStyle` method might fail due to a style not supported under the operating platform. Do you understand where that might refer to?

Comment: I am using wxPython 4.0.4. `wx.TE_READONLY` makes no difference. The new `style` is the existing style , with red as the text colour, so I don't expect that to be an issue.

Comment: I am using wxPython 2.8.11. So my code now is: 
`def OnHexMouse(self, event):
    curspos = self.Hex_text.GetInsertionPoint()
    charnum, linenum = self.Hex_text.PositionToXY(curspos)
    startmark = curspos - charnum
    linelen = self.Hex_text.GetLineLength(linenum)
    endmark = startmark + linelen
    oldstyle = self.Hex_text.GetDefaultStyle()
    newcolor = wx.Colour(255, 0, 0, 255)
    newstyle = wx.TextAttr(colText=newcolor)
    self.Hex_text.SetStyle(startmark, endmark, newstyle)`
...and it still returns False.

Comment: My software repositories no longer include wxpython 2.8. Perhaps there is a message in that.